# xlswrite overwrites entire excel spreadsheet

Tags: matlab, export-to-excel

In Matlab I need to generate one cell of data, that I had missed previously when I had run the program before, to an excel file. Unfortunately, when I try to specify the cell to write in `xlswrite` and run the program, it deletes the entire excel spreadsheet and only replaces that one generated cell. How do I go about adding one cell to an existing excel file without overwriting the entire file?

```
%// data is gathered and stored in predefined variables dice34, HD34, and MAE34. 

%// files specified have already been created and have been added data before.

rangeData = 'A7';

D = {dice34};
H = {HD34};
M = {MAE34};

fileNameD = 'DiceCoefficientReformatted34.xlsx';
fileNameH = 'HausdorffDistanceReformatted34.xlsx';
fileNameM = 'MeanAbsoluteErrorReformatted34.xlsx';

sheet = 'Sheet1';

xlswrite(fileNameD, D, sheet, rangeData);
xlswrite(fileNameH, H, sheet, rangeData);
xlswrite(fileNameM, M, sheet, rangeData);
```

Comment: Do you have Excel installed (see [the limitations section in the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html#zmw57dd0e797452))?

Comment: I do - I'm using it to check if it processed correctly

Comment: You could read in the whole sheet with [~,~,raw]=xlsread(fileNameD,sheet); and then modify the one cell and write it again.

Comment: Can you give me an example in code? I'm not quite sure how to use that.